# Cannot install the flutter application for ios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I got and Error which says that "found "xcode 10.1, build version 10b61". xcode 10.2 or greater is required to develop for ios. flutter ", Tried everything, but cannot make it work.

Its working on the Xcode, but unfortunately Its not working in VS Code.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a minimal reproducible example. Up to now your question is kind of vague, making it hard to see what you are doing and where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

The latest Xcode version is 11.3. Please update the Xcode in your mac machine and open Xcode to complete the installation of all necessary components.

Fluter requires Xcode command-line tools. to setup command-line tool run following in your terminal:

```
$ sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
$ sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

Detailed reference can be found in [Fluter iOS setup](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos). Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any option without updating. Thanks

Comment: have you tried setting `xcode-select` with your current Xcode version? Even if you find a workaround and start building your app, end of the data apple will start complaining about the Xcode version while you upload your app to the app store

Comment: I fully understand the difficulties of OP's, because I have a similar issue. There is no workaround other than upgrade the Xcode to 10.2 right now. As for me, I need to upgrade my current MBP (late 2011) because upgrade Xcode = upgrade OSX = upgrade MacBook Pro. :(

Comment: same here @Prabowo Murti

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, my macbook is late 2011 so I couldn't update to Mojave or Catalina which is required by xcode 10.2 and above.
for people like me reaching here, I just updated my mac to Catalina (the same 2011 model) using dosdude patcher located at [macOS Catalina Patcher](http://dosdude1.com/catalina/). it works like a charm, I installed the latest xcode and now all is fine.

Comment: Unable to install macOS Catalina Patcher